# GIT no puede crear archivo. fatal: Unable to create index.lock: File exists

Tags: git

No tengo más procesos ejecutándose.

> fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/Mauricio/Documents/PROGRAMACION/Github/PostCSS/.git/index.lock': File exists.
>
> Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
> an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
> are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
> may have crashed in this repository earlier:
> remove the file manually to continue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En ocasiones se queda algún proceso cuando se ejecutan 2 comandos git al mismo tiempo.

> fatal: Unable to create
>   'C:/Users/Mauricio/Documents/PROGRAMACION/Github/PostCSS/.git/index.lock':
>   File exists.

Elimina el archivo `index.lock` contenido en el directorio `.git/`

Remueve el archivo mediante:

```
rm -f ./.git/index.lock
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues justo eso que dice ahí...

Asegúrate de que no tienes algún otro proceso de git (gui o cli). Si el problema persiste entonces elimina manualmente el archivo `PostCSS/.git/index.lock`

Answer (score 0):

asegurate  bien que tengas configurado el nombre de usuario y mail   esto quiere  decir que  tu usuario y correo de github sean los mismos que en tu usuario y correo de git ej :

usa git config user.name  y git config user.email (para verificar lo dicho arriba ).
si necesitas  cambiarlo  usa git config user.name (tu usuario tal como esta en github sin comillas ni espacios)  y git config user.email (tu email tal como esta en github sin comillas ni espacios)